# extracting binary data out of 8-bit byte and converting it to primitive types [C++]

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, data-conversion

I have a vector of integers `vector<int>` that has 48 items in it. I want to extract binary data out of this(not sure if this is correct way to call it please edit it if it's wrong) i.e. a sequence of one or more bits and then convert them to a primitive type like int. I have come up with this solution:

```
int extractValue(vector<int> v, int startBit, int endBit) {
    int beginByteIndex = (startBit / 8);
    int endByteIndex = (endBit / 8);

    vector<bool> bits;
    bits.clear();

    int startIndex = startBit % 8;
    int endIndex = endBit % 8;
    int value = v[beginByteIndex];
    value = (value << startIndex);
    int temp = 8;
    if (beginByteIndex == endByteIndex) {
        temp = endIndex + 1;
    }
    for (int i = startIndex; i < temp; i++) {
        int temp = 0x80 & value;
        bits.push_back(temp);
        value <<= 1;
    }

    for (int i = beginByteIndex + 1; i < endByteIndex; i++) {
        value = v[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            int temp = 0x80 & value;
            bits.push_back(temp);
            value <<= 1;
        }
    }

    if (endByteIndex > beginByteIndex) {
        value = v[endByteIndex];
        for (int i = 0; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            int temp = 0x80 & value;
            bits.push_back(temp);
            value <<= 1;
        }
    }

    int size = bits.size();
    int p = 1;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += (bits[i] * p);
        p *= 2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

but this function is long, difficult to read and is done in C style. could someone please suggest a C++ way of doing this. I'm almost certain that C++ has a good, short and elegant way of doing this. also please edit the question so others with similar problem can benefit from it. Unfortunately My English is not that good to express it in a more general way.

**EDIT:**

as requested in comments for example I want to extract following information with following positions and length:

```
int year = extractValue(data, 0, 6);
int month = extractValue(data, 7, 10);
int day = extractValue(data, 11, 15);
```

Comment: give an example of the expected input and output. User 8 ints instead of 48 just to save typing

Comment: @pm100 ok I have added expected input and output example. please check.

Comment: This can probably be accomplished with just using `std::bitset` and `std::string`, converting the string to an int at the end.  Maybe no more than 10 lines of code.  BTW in your example, for (0,6) is 0 the leftmost bit or rightmost bit?  Maybe you should tell us exactly what those two numbers in the `extractValue` mean.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes 0 is the left most bit.

Comment: You will want to pass your vector by `const vector<int>&` not `vector<int>` or a copy may be made for every call to `extractValue`.

Comment: @Apriori yes I know but this is just a fast solution and is not supposed to be the final code. But thanks for reminding I'll put a `TODO:` as a comment in the function to keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution:

- convert each byte to hex string (`ostringstream`  or even `sprintf` can help), you got 2 digits, range is 0 to F.
- for each hex digit you can create the bitmap like this:

  0 = 0000,
  1 = 0001,
  2 = 0010,
  ...,
  F = 1111,
- add bits to the vector according to the bitmap
- to recover - you take 4 bits and translate it back to digit, then take 2 digits and convert back to byte (say by adding 0x to the hex, `isringstream` to byte).